# DualShock 4 controller audio over bluetooth?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, gamepad

Is there a way to stream game audio to the Dual Shock 4 controller over bluetooth in ubuntu?

Comment: You want to use that terrible speaker on the controller as a speaker for your game? Why? That speaker is really bad. To answer the question, no you can't right now and I doubt there ever will be an option to do this.

Comment: No, I want to plug my headphones into my controller.

Comment: Yeah, the controller apparently has a "PC" mode where it works as a standard gamepad, and a "PS4" mode where all of the other cool stuff on the controller is enabled (audio, touchpad), that I imagine is less standard and will take more reverse engineering.

Comment: @AndrewWagner It currently works over USB, and Audio over Bluetooth (both duplex and stereo) are common, standard, and for many devices supported in Ubuntu. It is probably a matter of marking this device to use one of those bluetooth profiles in addition to the game controller one.